# Get last element of string array in vb6?

Tags: vb6

How might one retrieve the last element of a string array in visual basic 6?

I'm dealing with filenames with multiple dots which are split into an array, and I want to manipulate only the extension. The following code works, but has a hardcoded element I want to remove.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim aPath() As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim realExt As String

    FileName = "A long dotty.file.name.txt"
    aPath = Split(FileName, ".")

    realExt = aPath(3) ' <-- how to not hardcode?'

    MsgBox ("The real extension is: " & realExt)
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just find the last index of the '.' character in the string?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think using Ubound should do the trick :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim aPath() As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim realExt As String

    FileName = "A long dotty.file.name.txt"
    aPath = Split(FileName, ".")

    realExt = aPath(UBound(aPath))

    MsgBox ("The real extension is: " & realExt)
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

```
realExt = aPath(ubound(aPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

However, if it's really just the extension you're after, this would do the job:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim lPos As Long
    Dim sRealExt As String

    sFileName = "A long dotty.file.name.txt"
    lPos = InStrRev(sFileName, ".")
    If lPos Then sRealExt = Mid$(sFileName, lPos + 1)
End Sub
```